# No remote start provisions

Tags: phrases

What would it mean when a vehicle description states "no remote start provisions".

Comment: The vehicle has no built-in facilities to permit the car's engine to be started remotely (eg, from a radio control module or a smart phone).  Remote start is popular north of here where people don't want to go outside in the -10F weather to start their cars in the morning.

Comment: @HotLicks What a load of wimps. The first car I had came with a starting handle. There was an electric starter too - but it didn't always work.

Comment: @WS2 - So, getting up at 5 AM in ten-below weather, you'd rather pull on your snowmobile suit and go out and crank the engine by hand than simply press a button while remaining warm and cozy in your house?

Comment: @HotLicks Well that was over 50 years ago.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I'd much rather just go out, start the car, and drive away, rather than wasting gas letting a car idle - which is really not an efficient way to warm it up.

Comment: @jamesqf -- When the temp is 25F below and the windows are frosted up it's incredibly convenient to start the car and let it warm up for a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

*provisions* refers to all the features that are (or in this case, could be) provided by the car.

*remote start* means the ability to turn the engine on from a distance, such as with a button on the key.

*no* means it doesn't have this.

So all together it means that the car doesn't have the feature that allows it to be started from a distance -- you can only turn it on from inside the car.